# What are the asymptotics of the $q$-binomial?

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, symmetric-functions, q-analogs

I have a rather basic question regarding the $q$-binomial $\begin{bmatrix}N \\ 
 r \end{bmatrix}=\frac{(1-q^N)(1-q^{N-1} ) \dots (1-q^{N-r+1})}{ (1-q)(1-q^2)\dots(1-q^r)  }$ as $N$ goes to infinity. On pages 26 and 27 of Macdonald's book on symmetric functions, it says that the $q$-binomial in this limit is given by

\begin{equation}
\lim_{N\to \infty }\begin{bmatrix}N \\
 r \end{bmatrix} =  \frac{1}{ (1-q)(1-q^2)\dots(1-q^r)  }~.
\end{equation}

My question is for what values of $q$ the above limit for the $q$-binomial holds. While it obviously holds when the absolute value  $| q |  <1$, it is not specified in Macdonald that this is the case (as far as I can tell), $q$ is simply stated to be indeterminate. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It should be clear it doesn't converge for $|q|>1$. The limit is clearly $0$ of $q$ is an $r$th root of unity. In general, if $q$ is an $m$th root of unity the $q$-binomial as a function of $N$ has period $m$. Otherwise if $|q|=1$ the $q$-binomial is clearly bounded but I imagine not convergent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can think of this as convergence for formal power series, so the topology here is discrete. This means that the coefficient at each power of $q$ should be eventually constant for the limit to exist. Indeed,
$$
\begin{split}
\begin{bmatrix}N\\r\end{bmatrix}&=\frac{(1-q^N)(1-q^{N-1})\dots(1-q^{N-r+1})}{ (1-q)(1-q^2)\dots(1-q^r)}\\
&=\frac{1}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\dots(1-q^r)}\cdot(1-q^{N-r+1}+\text{higher powers of $q$}),
\end{split}
$$
so the power series for $\begin{bmatrix}N\\r\end{bmatrix}$ and for $\frac{1}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\dots(1-q^r)}$ coincide up to power $q^{N-r}$. Letting $N\to\infty$, we get the desired limit.

Comment: I think this is a worthwhile tangent to bring up, but does not answer the original question, which is intended for the usual topology. (Or else it should be explicitly stated that switching up to the topology is a better way to understand the $q$-binomial in whatever context.)

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}N\\r\end{bmatrix}$ is a polynomial in $q$ of degree $r(N-r)$ with nonnegative integer coefficients, so it does not converge for $|q|>1$ as $N\to\infty$.